# How Will I come to know the previous details of MAC Address, Processors in ubuntu OS

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, operating-systems, hostname

I want to know that how one can get information about the previous details of MAC Address, mother board configurations(Processor details etc) in ubuntu OS once the motherboard is changed? I mean, Is there any place where these type of data is stored by system ? 
Kindly help me out ..
thank u ..

Comment: I don't know if there's a canonical source for this information, but a lot of it can be found by grepping old kern.log files (/var/log/kern.log.x, where .x is a number - higher numbers are older files).

Answer (score 1):

How long ago did you switch the hardware components?
Usually, each boot fills the kern.log with the detected hardware which was available when the system started up. Like user55325 wrote, you then simply have a look at those old files (/var/log/).

At least they give you the basic information.
I am not aware that Linux stores old hardware information somewhere.